# Improve Django queryset performance when using annotate Exists

Tags: django, django-queryset, query-performance

I have a queryset that returns a lot of data, it can be filtered by year which will return around 100k lines, or show all which will bring around 1 million lines.

The objective of this annotate is to generate a xlsx spreadsheet.

Models representation, `RelatedModel` is manytomany between `Model` and `AnotherModel`

```
Model:
    id
    field1
    field2
    field3

RelatedModel:
    foreign_key_model (Model)
    foreign_key_another (AnotherModel)
```

Queryset, if the relation exists it will annotate, this annotate is very slow and can take several minutes.

```
Model.objects.all().annotate(
    related_exists=Exists(RelatedModel.objects.filter(foreign_key_model=OuterRef('id'))),
    related_column=Case(
        When(related_exists=True, then=Value('The relation exists!')),
        When(related_exists=False, then=Value('The relation doesn't exist!')),
        default=Value('This is the default value!'),
        output_field=CharField(),
    )
).values_list(
    'related_column',
    'field1',
    'field2',
    'field3'
)
```

Comment: Use pagination?

Comment: The objective is to generate a spreadsheet (xlsx file)

Comment: Yes, you can write in batches.

Answer (score 7):

If only thing needed is to change how True / False is displayed in xlsx - one option is to just have one `related_exists` BooleanField annotation and later customize how it will be converted when creating xlsx document - i.e. in serializer. Database should store raw / unformatted values, and app prepare them to be shown to user.

Other things to consider:

- Indexes to speed-up filtering.
- If you have millions of records after filtering, in one table - maybe table partitioning could be considered.

---

**But let's look into raw sql of original query.** It will be like this:

```sql
SELECT [model_fields],
       EXISTS([CLIENT_SELECT]) AS related_exists,
       CASE
       WHEN EXISTS([CLIENT_SELECT]) = true THEN 'The relation exists!'
       WHEN EXISTS([CLIENT_SELECT]) = true THEN 'The relation does not exist!'
       ELSE 'The relation exists!'
       END AS related_column
FROM model;
```

And right away we can see **nested query for Exists CLIENT_SELECT** is there **3 times**. Even though it is exactly the same, it may be executed minimum 2 times and up to 3 times. Database may optimize it to be faster than 3x, but it still is not optimal as 1x.

First, `EXISTS` returns either True or False, we can leave just one check that it is True, making `'The relation does not exist!'` the default value.

```
    related_column=Case(
        When(related_exists=True, then=Value('The relation exists!')),
        default=Value('The relation does not exist!')
```

Why `related_column` performs same select again and not takes the value of `related_exists`?

Because we **cannot reference calculated columns** while calculating another columns - and this is database level constraint django knows about and duplicates expression.

Wait, then we actually do not need `related_exists` column, lets just leave `related_column` with CASE statement and 1 exists subquery.

Here comes Django - we cannot (till 3.0) use expressions in filters without annotating them first.

So, it our case it is like: in order to use `Exist` in `When`, we first need to add it as annotation, but it won't be used as a reference, but a full copy of expression.

---

**Good news!**

Since [Django 3.0](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/releases/3.0/#filter-expressions) we **can use expressions that output BooleanField directly in QuerySet filters, without having to first annotate**. `Exists` is one of such BooleaField expressions.

```
Model.objects.all().annotate(
    related_column=Case(
        When(
            Exists(RelatedModel.objects.filter(foreign_key_model=OuterRef('id'))),
            then=Value('The relation exists!'),
        ),
        default=Value('The relation doesn't exist!'),
        output_field=CharField(),
    )
)
```

And only one nested select, and one annotated field.

---

**Django 2.1, 2.2**

Here's the [commit](https://github.com/django/django/commit/4137fc2efce2dde48340728b8006fc6d66b9e3a5#diff-fe637a3ec6af9cbe2ee87293000e7c82) that finalized allowance of boolean expressions although many pre-conditions for it were added earlier. One of them is presence of `conditional` attribute on expression object and check for this attribute.

So, although **not recommended** and **not tested** it seems quite working little hack for Django 2.1, 2.2 (before there was no `conditional` check, and it will require more intrusive changes):

- create `Exists` expression instance
- monkey patch it with `conditional = True`
- use it as condition in `When` statement

```
related_model_exists = Exists(RelatedModel.objects.filter(foreign_key_model=OuterRef('id')))

setattr(related_model_exists, 'conditional', True)

Model.objects.all().annotate(
    related_column=Case(
        When(
            relate_model_exists,
            then=Value('The relation exists!'),
        ),
        default=Value('The relation doesn't exist!'),
        output_field=CharField(),
    )
)
```

---

**Related checks**

**`relatedmodel_set__isnull=True`** check is **not** suitable for several reasons:

- it performs `LEFT OUTER JOIN` - that is less efficient than `EXISTS`
- it performs `LEFT OUTER JOIN` - it joins tables, this makes it ONLY suitable in filter() condition (not in annotate - When), and only for OneToOne or OneToMany (One is on relatedmodel side) relations

Comment: setattr(related_model_exists, 'conditional', True) not works for dj 2 =(

Answer (score 2):

You can considerably simplify your query to:

```
from django.db.models import Count
Model.objects.all().annotate(
    related_column=Case(
        When(relatedmodel_set__isnull=True, then=Value("The relation doesn't exist!")), 
        default=Value("The relation exists!"), 
        output_field=CharField()
    )
)
```

Where `relatedmodel_set` is the `related_name` on your foreign key.